# Unable to get String in Activity sending from Service class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am sending String from a Service class which extends FirebaseMessagingService to MainActivity.java

But unable to fetch that into MainActivity.java getting null only, where I am doing mistake, many times I used Intent in my programs but only this time not getting data.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMessageService";
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String strMessage = "", strImageURI = "", strTrueOrFalse = "";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        strMessage = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");

        strImageURI = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");

        strTrueOrFalse = remoteMessage.getData().get("PushNotifyActivity");

        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(strImageURI);

        sendNotification(strMessage, bitmap, strTrueOrFalse);

    }


    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", "Testing");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** To testing string passing or not from here, I have given "Testing" as default String to get, but unfortunately even I am not getting same in a MainActivity.java.

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onNewIntent(getIntent());

    subscribeToPushService();

    }

private void subscribeToPushService() {

    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

}

@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    dbManager = new DBManager(MainActivity.this);
    dbManager.open();

    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationMessage");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MSG: "+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dbManager.insert(msg, "");

}
```

**Question:** Why I am getting null instead of String "Testing" in MainActivity.java

Comment: just want to clarify first, how do you start your MainActivity? by code or by click in the notification?

Comment: check for intent.hasExtras();

Comment: Triied to reproduce your code and everything seems to be working properly. Can your show your MainActivity.java's declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: try moving the code from `onNewIntent` to `onCreate`

Comment: if you are starting from home screen icon click. then ofcourse u'r gonna get null.. but by clicking notification, this should give u "Testing". I am curious whats that small silly mistake thats keep getting ignored by all of us.. lol..

Answer (score 2):

Just confirmed the Intent class from Android Source. And it seems there is no difference if you put data directly using `Intent.PutExtra(String,String)` or using bundle like `Intent.putExtras(bundle)`, similarly you can retrieve.

So only problem I think is with the flag on `PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT` as per documentation it says,

> Flag indicating that this PendingIntent can be used only once. For use with getActivity(Context, int, Intent, int), getBroadcast(Context, int, Intent, int), and getService(Context, int, Intent, int).
>   If set, after send() is called on it, it will be automatically canceled for you and any future attempt to send through it will fail.

So I think this is the problem.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#FLAG_ONE_SHOT

Answer (score 0):

Pass Update current Flag in `PendingIntent` like this:

```
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And remove this from intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

And Check weather you are getting your message in `messageBody` varaible

You getting Bundle instead of String.Change your `newIntent` Code Like this:

```
 @Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Intent:CALLED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    if (intent!= null) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Extras found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("NotificationMessage");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Open: "+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: In Notification Bar getting Message, but while logging not getting any message here: Log.d("MessageBody:", messageBody); what could be the reasons ? I followed your approach

Comment: Were you getting "Intent:CALLED"  toast ??

Comment: Thanks for your efforts yet not done, but I have posted updated code above, please check and let me know ! where I am doing mistake ? Now I am passing hardcoded string to test but always getting null in activity instead of string

Comment: I still did not get why you are using this `intent.getExtras()`

Comment: Change you `onNewIntent()` Method  code like which i have edited in the answer

Comment: Change the `PendingIntent` flag to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

Comment: I have already tried without using Bundle and intent.getExtras().... In short I tried the way you wrote above but still getting null only in place of String value and as you can see in my code, I am using FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT only.... don't know why this thing happening to me ?